# Windows stuck in reboot loop due to existing Scheduled Task

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a way to stop Task Scheduler on startup?

I ask because I have made mistake while creating task, and now my computer shuts down after 1 min.  That's not enough time to open the Task Scheduler and turn it off.

Comment: As a point of interest you used to be able to hold Shift on startup to solve this, but it's removed in 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have your tried starting the computer in safe mode, I don't think the task manager is active in that mode.

Comment: Ok, the safe mode didn't work, because it doesn't allow to use Task Scheduler (you can't see the tasks nor edit them) ... but luckily I set the option to run this task only on mine account (didn't have any other and the guest was turned off) but I could add new account with admins rights in the safe mode and it was a smooth ride from there :) Anyway thx for the tip about the safe mode, although I knew of it, it didn't flash my mind to use it :)

Answer (score 3):

- Start the computer in Safe Mode.
- Check these locations for your task:

`%systemroot%\System32\Tasks`
`%systemroot%\Tasks`

- Once you've identified it either delete it, or copy it someplace else.
- Reboot Windows into Normal Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot into safe Mode. Once there use regedit to delete the offending task.
It should be in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree\***yourtaskname***

Comment: Your answer is obsolete - user @CGA already suggested that.

Comment: @Davidenko All CGA said was "boot into safe mode" without providing any more information. Radame provided details on how to address the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the scheduled task that's running a shutdown command, then you can try stopping it from the command line:

```
shutdown -a
```

This will abort any currently running shutdown operation.

Comment: shutdown -a can only be used during the shutdown period, which afaik is not there if the shutdown is invoked as a task?